# Notification when a file changes?

Tags: c#, file, filesystemwatcher

Is there some mechanism by which I can be notified (in C#) when a file is modified on the disc?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381976/handling-multiple-change-events-in-filesystemwatcher/382996#382996) for more information on the FileSystemWatcher class and the events it raises.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

That would be [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Comment: The doc said using System.IO only https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 244):

You can use the [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) class.

```
public void CreateFileWatcher(string path)
{
    // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = path;
    /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and 
       the renaming of files or directories. */
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite 
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
    // Only watch text files.
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

    // Add event handlers.
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

// Define the event handlers.
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
   Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
}

private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice example.  I'll also point out that you can use the method WaitForChanged on FileSystemWatcher if you are looking for a blocking (synchronous) way to watch for changes.

Comment: Thanks for this example. The MSDN has pretty much the same [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Also, some people might want to watch a whole directory tree - use `watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;` to achieve that.

Comment: `OnChange` fires without actual change (_e.g: hitting `ctrl+s` without any actual change_), is there any way to detect fake changes?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani: Not that I know of, the only way seems to be to actually keep a snapshot of the file and compare that byte-wise to the current (presumably changed) version. The `FileSystemWatcher` only is able to detect events at the file system level (i.e. if the OS triggers an event). In your case Ctrl+S triggers such an event (whether that happens or not depends on the actual application though).

Comment: Is FileSystemWatcher cross-platform ?

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. I've got Valve's Steam changing appmanifest_appid.acf in the steamapps folder, and I'd like to get notified when the application updates. The file updates when the game starts to update, notepad++ detects the change and prompts to reload the file. But the `FileSystemWatcher` doesn't detect these changes. I coded it correctly, because I do get notified when I edit the manifest file in the notepad++ and press Ctrl+S.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `FileSystemWatcher`.  You can filter for modification events only.