# File watcher in windows service

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-services

I am beginner trying to develop a Windows service which keeps checking a folder (or group of folders) for any new file or changed files. As soon as it detects any new file or changes (to files or folders) then it copies the files (and any new folders) and paste it to another location.

I have done the same thing with a Windows Forms application but in a Windows Service I don't know what to do - how can I do this in a Windows Service?

Comment: Good for you, sounds great.

Comment: oki so we understand that you're developing the service, could you edit the question and let us know where you encountered dificulties and if you can post some code examples . thanks

Comment: Have you tried the FileSystemWatcher class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx#Y0

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Here is correct answer for this question

```
public static void MyMethod()
{
    String[] files = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\", "*.*");
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        var fileN = file.Substring(2);
        string destfile = "E:\\2nd folder" + fileN;
        File.Copy(file, destfile, true);
    }
}
```

polling is needed to watch the file after a fix interval of time....this code is watch the file 2sec

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
    timer.Interval = 2000;
    timer.Enabled = true; 
    MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes)

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  how we can complete this task using file watcher without timer

```
public void ProcessFile(string filepath)
    {
        var fileN ="newfilename";
        string destfile = "E:\\2nd folder" + fileN;
        File.Copy(filepath, destfile, true);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
       String[] files = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\", "*.*");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            ProcessFile(file);
        }
        var fw = new FileSystemWatcher("folderpath");
        fw.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        fw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        fw.Created += Newfileevent;

    }
    static void Newfileevent(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessFile(e.FullPath);

    }
```