# C# get notified when another process makes changes to a textfile

Tags: c#, text-files, inter-process-communicat

I would like to be notified in my C# application when another process makes changes to a particular textfile.

The reason for this is that I launch a 3rd party tool from my application in order to retrieve some information about a device. this tool saves the current state of the device into an ini file. This takes some undetermined time, but I want to react and read the state information as soon as it's available.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher class.
Something like this:

```
string fileToWatch = @"C:\MyFile.txt";
fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(fileToWatch);

void fileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Name +  " has changed");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor file changes using [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Also, see [Notification when a file changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes) for more info.