# i want to check file exist in folder continously in c#

Tags: c#, ftp

I have requirement to process file as soon as someone put the file in ftp location
and i want to create c# code on windows server

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes

Comment: Did you try anything and get an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use FileSystemWatcher.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

public class Watcher
{

    public static void Main()
    {
    Run();

    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        // If a directory is not specified, exit program. 
        if(args.Length != 2)
        {
            // Display the proper way to call the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: Watcher.exe (directory)");
            return;
        }

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = args[1];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Define the event handlers. 
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
       Console.WriteLine("File: " +  e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F

Comment: Can this code work in background in windows service  ??

Comment: Yes you can create background task with this. This code may not work exactly but filesystemwatcher will.