# Make my program wait for a second before performing an action

Tags: c#

I have something like :

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            string ngdx = "*ngdx";
            string atdx = "*atdx";

            for (;;)
            {
                try
                {

                    string[] convertngdx = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\folder", ngdx);
                    string[] convertatdx = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\folder", atdx);


                    foreach (var convertngd in convertngdx)
                    {
                        File.Move(convertngd, Path.ChangeExtension(convertngd, ".ngd"));
                    }
                    foreach (var convertatd in convertatdx)
                    {
                        File.Move(convertatd, Path.ChangeExtension(convertatd, ".atd"));
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

I start my app and every time a `.ngdx` and `.atdx` file is send to the `folder` it automatically converts it to `.ngd` and `.atd`.

My problem is that it instantly converts them , and I want it to wait for a second before converting them.

I used `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` but it doesn't quite seem to work,I think because when I run my app the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` is called and then after a second it is never called again.

The idea is every time a new `.ngdx` or `.atdx` is send to the `folder` I want it to wait for a second before converting them.

Comment: Put the sleep in the for loop?

Comment: Sitting in a loop like this is going to tie up the UI thread (this looks like a WinForms application...). Have you considered using a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)? ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/721743/39709))

Comment: Very good idea @RichardEverett

Comment: I'd use a timer that is started when the method is called and the conversion is done in the timer's callback/elapsed event. The timer won't block the UI thread.

Comment: A debugger breakpoint is an excellent way to produce delays that are **exactly** as long as you need them to be.

Comment: @RichardEverett I did not know about the `FileSystemWatcher` thank you a lot for telling me about it :) you can tag it as an answer so I can close this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to using an infinite `for` loop (which will tie up the UI thread) you could use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx). ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/721743/39709))