# How to get type file with not use extension in c#

Tags: c#, window

I use this code for get extensions in c# windows application:

```
FileInfo oFile = new FileInfo(file);
string strType = oFile.Extension;
```

its working.

but, If the user has changed the file extension, its not working.

This method displays the appearance extension. please help me for another method.

Comment: There is no MacOS equivalent of file types in Windows. The extension is a hint to the OS as to the filetype, if the user changes the extension, they had better know what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If the user changes the file extension, then your data is now stale. You may want to subscribe to file change events. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes) for more information.