# How can I save an image frequently to a file in Windows Forms (C#)?

Tags: c#, windows

I wrote something in C# like

```
while(1){
  Bitmap b = BitMapFromSomewhereElse();
  b.save("a.jpg");
}
```

in order to let the image update real-time. But I always get System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: Generic error in GDI+

What's the problem here? Maybe I'm writing too fast, if I do this loop 500ms a time, the error will come out after several seconds, and if I do this 5000 ms a time, the error does not appear. I searched and tried a lot of methods, like calling Dispose() or using(b=...)... but none of those worked.

Comment: This is generally a horrible way to handle something.
Where is BitMapFromSomewhereElse() coming from?
If it is a file..
See this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes
Otherwise.. you could put a timer in there.. sleeping is generally a bad practice but not nearly as bad as WHILE(TRUE)

Comment: If you are constantly saving the file, probably you won't be able to use or read the file anywhere else. Also this is a good way to have your program flagged as potentially dangerous by an antivirus software.

Comment: Use a `FileSystemWatcher` like in @SeñorCMasMas's linked post. Using an infinite loop not only locks up the thread, but having it check every X seconds is not "real time". It's going to be *incredibly* wasteful to be saving a file to disk that often. (and **definitely** use `using` blocks)

Comment: This code consumes 100% CPU time continuously. It would last about 2 seconds on my machine before I deleted it and hurried to give an extremely negative review on every site I could find related to the program.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the problem is you're not releasing resources. `Bitmap` is a disposable object, so you should be disposing it:

```
while(1){
    using (Bitmap b = BitMapFromSomewhereElse()) {
        b.save("a.jpg");
    }
}
```

It really depends on whether `BitMapFromSomewhereElse` is creating a new bitmap every time you call it, or if it's just returning a reference to an existing bitmap. If the former, then you need to call `Dispose`. If the latter, then `Dispose` shouldn't be necessary, so long as whatever creates the bitmap originally ends up disposing it at some point.